# Implement a "Find all" algorithm that displays matched lines in a table, and jumps to line when table cell clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I would like to implement functionality for being able to search a `QPlainTextEdit` for a query string, and display all matched lines in a table. Selecting a row in the table should move the cursor to the correct line in the document.

Below is a working example that finds all matches and displays them in a table. How can I get to the selected line number in the string that the plaintextedit holds? I could instead use the `match.capturedEnd()` and `match.capturedStart()` to show the matches, but line numbers are a more intuitive thing to think of, rather than the character index matches.

#### MWE (rather long sample text for fun)

```
import PySide6.QtCore as qtc
import PySide6.QtGui as qtg
import PySide6.QtWidgets as qtw


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        qtw.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Application')
        self.fileViewer = qtw.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.lineEditQuery = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.tableResults = qtw.QTableWidget()
        self.tableResults.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableResults.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Line Number', 'Matched Line'])
        self.buttonFind = qtw.QPushButton('Find All')

        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.fileViewer)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEditQuery)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonFind)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableResults)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Set some properties of QTableWidget
        self.tableResults.setSizeAdjustPolicy(qtw.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableResults.setSelectionBehavior(self.tableResults.SelectRows)

        # Insert search query
        self.lineEditQuery.setText('simplicity itself')

        # Connect button click event
        self.buttonFind.clicked.connect(self.findAll)

    def findAll(self):
        """Collect matches in dict and pass on the insert method."""
        query = qtc.QRegularExpression(self.lineEditQuery.text())
        fileContents = self.fileViewer.toPlainText().splitlines()

        result = {}
        for i, line in enumerate(fileContents):
            match = query.match(line)
            if match.hasMatch():
                result[i] = line
                match.capturedEnd()

        self.insertMatches(result)

    def insertMatches(self, matches):
        self.tableResults.setRowCount(len(matches))

        rowCounter = 0
        for i, line in matches.items():
            itemNumber = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(i))
            itemLine = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(line)
            self.tableResults.setItem(rowCounter, 0, itemNumber)
            self.tableResults.setItem(rowCounter, 1, itemLine)
            rowCounter += 1
        self.tableResults.resizeColumnsToContents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SAMPLE = """




                            THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES

                                   Arthur Conan Doyle



                                    Table of contents

                   A Scandal in Bohemia





                                  A SCANDAL IN BOHEMIA





                                    Table of contents
                                         Chapter 1



              CHAPTER I



         To Sherlock Holmes she is always the woman. I have seldom heard him
         mention her under any other name. In his eyes she eclipses and
         predominates the whole of her sex. It was not that he felt any
         emotion akin to love for Irene Adler. All emotions, and that one
         particularly, were abhorrent to his cold, precise but admirably
         balanced mind. He was, I take it, the most perfect reasoning and
         observing machine that the world has seen, but as a lover he would
         have placed himself in a false position. He never spoke of the softer
         passions, save with a gibe and a sneer. They were admirable things
         for the observer--excellent for drawing the veil from men's motives
         and actions. But for the trained reasoner to admit such intrusions
         into his own delicate and finely adjusted temperament was to
         introduce a distracting factor which might throw a doubt upon all his
         mental results. Grit in a sensitive instrument, or a crack in one of
         his own high-power lenses, would not be more disturbing than a strong
         emotion in a nature such as his. And yet there was but one woman to
         him, and that woman was the late Irene Adler, of dubious and
         questionable memory.

         I had seen little of Holmes lately. My marriage had drifted us away
         from each other. My own complete happiness, and the home-centred
         interests which rise up around the man who first finds himself master
         of his own establishment, were sufficient to absorb all my attention,
         while Holmes, who loathed every form of society with his whole
         Bohemian soul, remained in our lodgings in Baker Street, buried among
         his old books, and alternating from week to week between cocaine and
         ambition, the drowsiness of the drug, and the fierce energy of his
         own keen nature. He was still, as ever, deeply attracted by the study
         of crime, and occupied his immense faculties and extraordinary powers
         of observation in following out those clues, and clearing up those
         mysteries which had been abandoned as hopeless by the official
         police. From time to time I heard some vague account of his doings:
         of his summons to Odessa in the case of the Trepoff murder, of his
         clearing up of the singular tragedy of the Atkinson brothers at
         Trincomalee, and finally of the mission which he had accomplished so
         delicately and successfully for the reigning family of Holland.
         Beyond these signs of his activity, however, which I merely shared
         with all the readers of the daily press, I knew little of my former
         friend and companion.

         One night--it was on the twentieth of March, 1888--I was returning
         from a journey to a patient (for I had now returned to civil
         practice), when my way led me through Baker Street. As I passed the
         well-remembered door, which must always be associated in my mind with
         my wooing, and with the dark incidents of the Study in Scarlet, I was
         seized with a keen desire to see Holmes again, and to know how he was
         employing his extraordinary powers. His rooms were brilliantly lit,
         and, even as I looked up, I saw his tall, spare figure pass twice in
         a dark silhouette against the blind. He was pacing the room swiftly,
         eagerly, with his head sunk upon his chest and his hands clasped
         behind him. To me, who knew his every mood and habit, his attitude
         and manner told their own story. He was at work again. He had risen
         out of his drug-created dreams and was hot upon the scent of some new
         problem. I rang the bell and was shown up to the chamber which had
         formerly been in part my own.

         His manner was not effusive. It seldom was; but he was glad, I think,
         to see me. With hardly a word spoken, but with a kindly eye, he waved
         me to an armchair, threw across his case of cigars, and indicated a
         spirit case and a gasogene in the corner. Then he stood before the
         fire and looked me over in his singular introspective fashion.

         "Wedlock suits you," he remarked. "I think, Watson, that you have put
         on seven and a half pounds since I saw you."

         "Seven!" I answered.

         "Indeed, I should have thought a little more. Just a trifle more, I
         fancy, Watson. And in practice again, I observe. You did not tell me
         that you intended to go into harness."

         "Then, how do you know?"

         "I see it, I deduce it. How do I know that you have been getting
         yourself very wet lately, and that you have a most clumsy and
         careless servant girl?"

         "My dear Holmes," said I, "this is too much. You would certainly have
         been burned, had you lived a few centuries ago. It is true that I had
         a country walk on Thursday and came home in a dreadful mess, but as I
         have changed my clothes I can't imagine how you deduce it. As to Mary
         Jane, she is incorrigible, and my wife has given her notice, but
         there, again, I fail to see how you work it out."

         He chuckled to himself and rubbed his long, nervous hands together.

         "It is simplicity itself," said he; "my eyes tell me that on the
         inside of your left shoe, just where the firelight strikes it, the
         leather is scored by six almost parallel cuts. Obviously they have
         been caused by someone who has very carelessly scraped round the
         edges of the sole in order to remove crusted mud from it. Hence, you
         see, my double deduction that you had been out in vile weather, and
         that you had a particularly malignant boot-slitting specimen of the
         London slavey. As to your practice, if a gentleman walks into my
         rooms smelling of iodoform, with a black mark of nitrate of silver
         upon his right forefinger, and a bulge on the right side of his
         top-hat to show where he has secreted his stethoscope, I must be
         dull, indeed, if I do not pronounce him to be an active member of the
         medical profession."

         I could not help laughing at the ease with which he explained his
         process of deduction. "When I hear you give your reasons," I
         remarked, "the thing always appears to me to be so ridiculously
         simple that I could easily do it myself, though at each successive
         instance of your reasoning I am baffled until you explain your
         process. And yet I believe that my eyes are as good as yours."

         "Quite so," he answered, lighting a cigarette, and throwing himself
         down into an armchair. "You see, but you do not observe. The
         distinction is clear. For example, you have frequently seen the steps
         which lead up from the hall to this room."

         "Frequently."

         "How often?"

         "Well, some hundreds of times."

         "Then how many are there?"

         "How many? I don't know."

         "Quite so! You have not observed. And yet you have seen. That is just
         my point. Now, I know that there are seventeen steps, because I have
         both seen and observed. By-the-way, since you are interested in these
         little problems, and since you are good enough to chronicle one or
         two of my trifling experiences, you may be interested in this." He
         threw over a sheet of thick, pink-tinted note-paper which had been
         lying open upon the table. "It came by the last post," said he. "Read
         it aloud."

         The note was undated, and without either signature or address.

         "There will call upon you to-night, at a quarter to eight o'clock,"
         it said, "a gentleman who desires to consult you upon a matter of the
         very deepest moment. Your recent services to one of the royal houses
         of Europe have shown that you are one who may safely be trusted with
         matters which are of an importance which can hardly be exaggerated.
         This account of you we have from all quarters received. Be in your
         chamber then at that hour, and do not take it amiss if your visitor
         wear a mask."

         "This is indeed a mystery," I remarked. "What do you imagine that it
         means?"

         "I have no data yet. It is a capital mistake to theorize before one
         has data. Insensibly one begins to twist facts to suit theories,
         instead of theories to suit facts. But the note itself. What do you
         deduce from it?"

         I carefully examined the writing, and the paper upon which it was
         written.

         "The man who wrote it was presumably well to do," I remarked,
         endeavouring to imitate my companion's processes. "Such paper could
         not be bought under half a crown a packet. It is peculiarly strong
         and stiff."

         "Peculiar--that is the very word," said Holmes. "It is not an English
         paper at all. Hold it up to the light."

         I did so, and saw a large "E" with a small "g," a "P," and a large
         "G" with a small "t" woven into the texture of the paper.

         "What do you make of that?" asked Holmes.

         "The name of the maker, no doubt; or his monogram, rather."

         "Not at all. The 'G' with the small 't' stands for 'Gesellschaft,'
         which is the German for 'Company.' It is a customary contraction like
         our 'Co.' 'P,' of course, stands for 'Papier.' Now for the 'Eg.' Let
         us glance at our Continental Gazetteer." He took down a heavy brown
         volume from his shelves. "Eglow, Eglonitz--here we are, Egria. It is
         in a German-speaking country--in Bohemia, not far from Carlsbad.
         'Remarkable as being the scene of the death of Wallenstein, and for
         its numerous glass-factories and paper-mills.' Ha, ha, my boy, what
         do you make of that?" His eyes sparkled, and he sent up a great blue
         triumphant cloud from his cigarette.

         "The paper was made in Bohemia," I said.

         "Precisely. And the man who wrote the note is a German. Do you note
         the peculiar construction of the sentence--'This account of you we
         have from all quarters received.' A Frenchman or Russian could not
         have written that. It is the German who is so uncourteous to his
         verbs. It only remains, therefore, to discover what is wanted by this
         German who writes upon Bohemian paper and prefers wearing a mask to
         showing his face. And here he comes, if I am not mistaken, to resolve
         all our doubts."

         As he spoke there was the sharp sound of horses' hoofs and grating
         wheels against the curb, followed by a sharp pull at the bell. Holmes
         whistled.

         "A pair, by the sound," said he. "Yes," he continued, glancing out of
         the window. "A nice little brougham and a pair of beauties. A hundred
         and fifty guineas apiece. There's money in this case, Watson, if
         there is nothing else."

         "I think that I had better go, Holmes."

         "Not a bit, Doctor. Stay where you are. I am lost without my Boswell.
         And this promises to be interesting. It would be a pity to miss it."

         "But your client--"

         "Never mind him. I may want your help, and so may he. Here he comes.
         Sit down in that armchair, Doctor, and give us your best attention."

         A slow and heavy step, which had been heard upon the stairs and in
         the passage, paused immediately outside the door. Then there was a
         loud and authoritative tap.

         "Come in!" said Holmes.

         A man entered who could hardly have been less than six feet six
         inches in height, with the chest and limbs of a Hercules. His dress
         was rich with a richness which would, in England, be looked upon as
         akin to bad taste. Heavy bands of astrakhan were slashed across the
         sleeves and fronts of his double-breasted coat, while the deep blue
         cloak which was thrown over his shoulders was lined with
         flame-coloured silk and secured at the neck with a brooch which
         consisted of a single flaming beryl. Boots which extended halfway up
         his calves, and which were trimmed at the tops with rich brown fur,
         completed the impression of barbaric opulence which was suggested by
         his whole appearance. He carried a broad-brimmed hat in his hand,
         while he wore across the upper part of his face, extending down past
         the cheekbones, a black vizard mask, which he had apparently adjusted
         that very moment, for his hand was still raised to it as he entered.
         From the lower part of the face he appeared to be a man of strong
         character, with a thick, hanging lip, and a long, straight chin
         suggestive of resolution pushed to the length of obstinacy.

         "You had my note?" he asked with a deep harsh voice and a strongly
         marked German accent. "I told you that I would call." He looked from
         one to the other of us, as if uncertain which to address.

         "Pray take a seat," said Holmes. "This is my friend and colleague,
         Dr. Watson, who is occasionally good enough to help me in my cases.
         Whom have I the honour to address?"

         "You may address me as the Count Von Kramm, a Bohemian nobleman. I
         understand that this gentleman, your friend, is a man of honour and
         discretion, whom I may trust with a matter of the most extreme
         importance. If not, I should much prefer to communicate with you
         alone."

         I rose to go, but Holmes caught me by the wrist and pushed me back
         into my chair. "It is both, or none," said he. "You may say before
         this gentleman anything which you may say to me."

         The Count shrugged his broad shoulders. "Then I must begin," said he,
         "by binding you both to absolute secrecy for two years; at the end of
         that time the matter will be of no importance. At present it is not
         too much to say that it is of such weight it may have an influence
         upon European history."

         "I promise," said Holmes.

         "And I."

         "You will excuse this mask," continued our strange visitor. "The
         august person who employs me wishes his agent to be unknown to you,
         and I may confess at once that the title by which I have just called
         myself is not exactly my own."

         "I was aware of it," said Holmes dryly.

         "The circumstances are of great delicacy, and every precaution has to
         be taken to quench what might grow to be an immense scandal and
         seriously compromise one of the reigning families of Europe. To speak
         plainly, the matter implicates the great House of Ormstein,
         hereditary kings of Bohemia."

         "I was also aware of that," murmured Holmes, settling himself down in
         his armchair and closing his eyes.

         Our visitor glanced with some apparent surprise at the languid,
         lounging figure of the man who had been no doubt depicted to him as
         the most incisive reasoner and most energetic agent in Europe. Holmes
         slowly reopened his eyes and looked impatiently at his gigantic
         client.

         "If your Majesty would condescend to state your case," he remarked,
         "I should be better able to advise you."

         The man sprang from his chair and paced up and down the room in
         uncontrollable agitation. Then, with a gesture of desperation, he
         tore the mask from his face and hurled it upon the ground. "You are
         right," he cried; "I am the King. Why should I attempt to conceal
         it?"

         "Why, indeed?" murmured Holmes. "Your Majesty had not spoken before I
         was aware that I was addressing Wilhelm Gottsreich Sigismond von
         Ormstein, Grand Duke of Cassel-Felstein, and hereditary King of
         Bohemia."

         "But you can understand," said our strange visitor, sitting down once
         more and passing his hand over his high white forehead, "you can
         understand that I am not accustomed to doing such business in my own
         person. Yet the matter was so delicate that I could not confide it to
         an agent without putting myself in his power. I have come incognito
         from Prague for the purpose of consulting you."

         "Then, pray consult," said Holmes, shutting his eyes once more.

         "The facts are briefly these: Some five years ago, during a lengthy
         visit to Warsaw, I made the acquaintance of the well-known
         adventuress, Irene Adler. The name is no doubt familiar to you."

         "Kindly look her up in my index, Doctor," murmured Holmes without
         opening his eyes. For many years he had adopted a system of docketing
         all paragraphs concerning men and things, so that it was difficult to
         name a subject or a person on which he could not at once furnish
         information. In this case I found her biography sandwiched in between
         that of a Hebrew rabbi and that of a staff-commander who had written
         a monograph upon the deep-sea fishes.

         "Let me see!" said Holmes. "Hum! Born in New Jersey in the year 1858.
         Contralto--hum! La Scala, hum! Prima donna Imperial Opera of
         Warsaw--yes! Retired from operatic stage--ha! Living in London--quite
         so! Your Majesty, as I understand, became entangled with this young
         person, wrote her some compromising letters, and is now desirous of
         getting those letters back."

         "Precisely so. But how--"

         "Was there a secret marriage?"

         "None."

         "No legal papers or certificates?"

         "None."

         "Then I fail to follow your Majesty. If this young person should
         produce her letters for blackmailing or other purposes, how is she to
         prove their authenticity?"

         "There is the writing."

         "Pooh, pooh! Forgery."

         "My private note-paper."

         "Stolen."

         "My own seal."

         "Imitated."

         "My photograph."

         "Bought."

         "We were both in the photograph."

         "Oh, dear! That is very bad! Your Majesty has indeed committed an
         indiscretion."

         "I was mad--insane."

         "You have compromised yourself seriously."

         "I was only Crown Prince then. I was young. I am but thirty now."

         "It must be recovered."

         "We have tried and failed."

         "Your Majesty must pay. It must be bought."

         "She will not sell."

         "Stolen, then."

         "Five attempts have been made. Twice burglars in my pay ransacked her
         house. Once we diverted her luggage when she travelled. Twice she has
         been waylaid. There has been no result."

         "No sign of it?"

         "Absolutely none."

         Holmes laughed. "It is quite a pretty little problem," said he.

         "But a very serious one to me," returned the King reproachfully.

         "Very, indeed. And what does she propose to do with the photograph?"

         "To ruin me."

         "But how?"

         "I am about to be married."

         "So I have heard."

         "To Clotilde Lothman von Saxe-Meningen, second daughter of the King
         of Scandinavia. You may know the strict principles of her family. She
         is herself the very soul of delicacy. A shadow of a doubt as to my
         conduct would bring the matter to an end."

         "And Irene Adler?"

         "Threatens to send them the photograph. And she will do it. I know
         that she will do it. You do not know her, but she has a soul of
         steel. She has the face of the most beautiful of women, and the mind
         of the most resolute of men. Rather than I should marry another
         woman, there are no lengths to which she would not go--none."

         "You are sure that she has not sent it yet?"

         "I am sure."

         "And why?"

         "Because she has said that she would send it on the day when the
         betrothal was publicly proclaimed. That will be next Monday."

         "Oh, then we have three days yet," said Holmes with a yawn. "That is
         very fortunate, as I have one or two matters of importance to look
         into just at present. Your Majesty will, of course, stay in London
         for the present?"

         "Certainly. You will find me at the Langham under the name of the
         Count Von Kramm."

         "Then I shall drop you a line to let you know how we progress."

         "Pray do so. I shall be all anxiety."

         "Then, as to money?"

         "You have carte blanche."

         "Absolutely?"

         "I tell you that I would give one of the provinces of my kingdom to
         have that photograph."

         "And for present expenses?"

         The King took a heavy chamois leather bag from under his cloak and
         laid it on the table.

         "There are three hundred pounds in gold and seven hundred in notes,"
         he said.

         Holmes scribbled a receipt upon a sheet of his note-book and handed
         it to him.

         "And Mademoiselle's address?" he asked.

         "Is Briony Lodge, Serpentine Avenue, St. John's Wood."

         Holmes took a note of it. "One other question," said he. "Was the
         photograph a cabinet?"

         "It was."

         "Then, good-night, your Majesty, and I trust that we shall soon have
         some good news for you. And good-night, Watson," he added, as the
         wheels of the royal brougham rolled down the street. "If you will be
         good enough to call to-morrow afternoon at three o'clock I should
         like to chat this little matter over with you."




         ----------
         This text is provided to you "as-is" without any warranty. No
         warranties of any kind, expressed or implied, are made to you as to
         the text or any medium it may be on, including but not limited to
         warranties of merchantablity or fitness for a particular purpose.

         This text was formatted from various free ASCII and HTML variants.
         See http://sherlock-holm.es for an electronic form of this text and
         additional information about it.

         This text comes from the collection's version 3.1.
    """

    app = qtw.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.fileViewer.insertPlainText(SAMPLE)
    mw.buttonFind.clicked.emit()
    mw.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get to the selected line"?

Comment: I mean move the cursor in fileViewer to the line number where a match was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move the cursor to a specified position, it's necessary to use the underlying [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) using [`document()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document).
Through [`findBlockByLineNumber`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#findBlockByLineNumber) you can construct a [QTextCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html) and use [`setTextCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#setTextCursor) to "apply" that cursor (including the actual caret position) to the plain text.

```
    def goToLine(self, line):
        block = self.fileViewer.document().findBlockByLineNumber(line)
        self.fileViewer.setTextCursor(qtg.QTextCursor(block))
        self.fileViewer.setFocus()
```

Since you will be working with QTextDocument and QTextCursor anyway, I suggest you to avoid searching line by line, since QTextDocument already provides a more compliant and extensible interface through [`find()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#find-5):

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.tableResults.itemClicked.connect(self.goToLine)

    def findAll(self):
        self.tableResults.setRowCount(0)
        query = qtc.QRegularExpression(self.lineEditQuery.text())
        doc = self.fileViewer.document()
        cursor = qtg.QTextCursor(doc)
        rowCounter = 0
        while True:
            cursor = doc.find(query, cursor)
            if cursor.isNull():
                break
            self.tableResults.insertRow(rowCounter)
            block = cursor.block()
            itemNumber = qtw.QTableWidgetItem()
            # set the data as integer, not as string; you cannot do that using
            # QTableWidgetItem constructor
            itemNumber.setData(qtc.Qt.DisplayRole, block.firstLineNumber())
            itemLine = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(block.text())
            self.tableResults.setItem(rowCounter, 0, itemNumber)
            self.tableResults.setItem(rowCounter, 1, itemLine)
            rowCounter += 1
        self.tableResults.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def goToLine(self, item):
        line = self.tableResults.model().index(item.row(), 0).data()
        block = self.fileViewer.document().findBlockByLineNumber(line)
        self.fileViewer.setTextCursor(qtg.QTextCursor(block))
        self.fileViewer.setFocus()
```

While a bit difficult to get used with, using the QTextCursor interface has a lot of benefits. For instance, you could set the matched cursor (which includes the selection of the found text) as item data, and set *that* cursor for the plain text; the result is that not only you'll get the correct position, but you'll also have the matched text automatically selected:

```
    def findAll(self):
            # ...
            itemNumber = qtw.QTableWidgetItem()
            itemNumber.setData(qtc.Qt.DisplayRole, block.firstLineNumber())
            # since the cursor is being reused for the search, you must
            # construct a *new* instance based on it
            itemNumber.setData(qtc.Qt.UserRole, qtg.QTextCursor(cursor))
            # ...

    def goToLine(self, item):
        index = self.tableResults.model().index(item.row(), 0)
        cursor = index.data(qtc.Qt.UserRole)
        self.fileViewer.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.fileViewer.setFocus()
```

<sup>Note: you should use `self.tableResults.setEditTriggers(self.tableResults.NoEditTriggers)` to avoid item editing in the table</sup>

Comment: Great, thanks! I will go for the quicker solution for now, but will eventually try to make use of the cursor interface as advised!